# How can I determine the appropriate color,font for a website based on target group?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, design-patterns, design, css

I am a web designer and often my clients ask me these kind of questions:

- What kind of site colors reflect my product?
- If my target group is of low income, what kind of colors/shapes does my website need to have?
- What font should I use if my product is considered luxurious?
- If my client has a target group of 50+, what kind of font combination is better?

I am asking if there is a general guideline that will help me with these kind of critical questions or a place to start reading?

Comment: The general guideline for those questions is to answer "it depends on a lot of things..."

Comment: I know.But it should be a general guidline / tips that I could refer.Any idea?

Comment: Not really. That document would be never ending because there are so many variations that depend on just so many factors.

Comment: It's not really a set of tips, but a process. Objective and subjective elements go into the design process which includes iterations until a final product comes out the other end. You really need to go through the process.

Comment: Assuming it is a process who is responsible and able to determine the steps of that process? The Web Designer or a marketer? In order to determine for example which color or font fits into a glamurous product who is determing it?

Comment: I think that the answer to your last comment is that it's a team effort b/w Marketing, Design etc. This question is most likely going to be closed but you might find some inspiration here: http://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-science-to-picking-colors-that-work-well-together-or-is-it-just-subjective

Answer (score 2):

I found this particularly insightful : http://www.colormatters.com/color-symbolism/global-color-survey.

After taking the survey, the results were as follows.

Over 130,000 people from all points on the globe took the survey. Here are the results:

- Happy - Yellow
- Pure - White
- Good Luck - Green
- Good-tasting - Red (tomato)
- Dignity - Dark Blue
- High Technology - Silver
- Sexiness - Red (tomato)
- Mourning - Black
- Expensive - Gold
- Inexpensive - Brown
- Powerful - Red (tomato)
- Dependable - Blue
- High Quality - Gold
- Nausea - Muted Yellow
- Deity - White
- Bad Luck - Black
- Favorite Color - Blue
- Least Favorite Color - Dark Yellow

Most of it seems common to people from all across the world. But once again, this is the majority of the results. I haven't been able to find the actual numbers to get an idea as to what different parts of the world perceive as their preferred color for different instances.

http://www.colorcom.com/research/demographic-research-about-color
They say they have actual demographic data for different regions and specific users too.

Answer (score 1):

When clients say they want to transmit something, I normally ask them for examples of what products, logos or slogans they have in mind at that time.

My idea of luxurous may not be exactly the same of my client, so through examples and exploring more of their public I can have more of those informations. Maybe people from one country think golden colors are "deluxe" and in other one green colors. There're many factors to take in account.

Months ago I tried to follow those infographs that describe colors and their effects on people. But results weren't as expected, and I was back to A/B testing.

Comment: normally the client takes advises from a marketer.And comes to me and say "I want this color and this font"...In most of my cases doesn't really fits his case and I know from the begining that there is going to be a poor design. So where can I find these "infographics" that are based on data per country in order to have something in my hand as an argument against my clients?

Comment: @kost, I make google/pinterest searches for it to gather data. When I see many infographs saying the same thing, I present them to my client as an advice. Example:
http://imgs.abduzeedo.com/files/best_week/color-infographics-03.jpg

Comment: Thanks @Patrick.Do you have any relevant infographic info for fonts or shapes(especially the first)?